# Python Multi Threading with Blocking I/O

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, io, gil

My application uses multiple I/O blocking (network) requests that take a while to complete. 
I tried using multi threading but it doesn't appear to bring any speedup, I'm guessing it's something to do with Python's GIL.

The thing is all of the requests can be done concurrently and have no dependencies on each other. How do I solve this performance issue?

My code

```
import threading
import urllib2
import time
def send_request(url, count_str):
    start_time = time.time()
    urllib2.urlopen(url)
    print "Request " + count_str + " took " + str(time.time() - start_time) + " started at " + str(start_time)

count = 0
for url in open('urllist.txt'):
    t = threading.Thread(target=send_request, args = (url.strip(), str(count)))
    t.start()
    count+=1
```

The output is

```
Request 1 took 5.0150949955 started at 1458789266.78
Request 2 took 10.0112490654 started at 1458789266.79
Request 0 took 15.024559021 started at 1458789266.78
Request 3 took 20.016972065 started at 1458789266.79
```

The urls in urllist.txt point to a server I'm running locally that take  5 seconds to respond. 
As you can see they all "start" at the same time, but they are blocking.

Comment: You can show us your code :)

Comment: @Signal updated it =) I'm very new to multithreading in Python so could be quite a lot wrong with it

Comment: How is `q.join()` supposed to return? Nothing in your code is processing the `Queue` to call `.get()` let alone `.task_done()`. You're also not returning anything from `get_and_read_url`, so you're just enqueuing `None`. Finally, I'll note: For threading in general, and `Queue`s in particular, Python 2 is _bad_; if you can move to more recent Python ([3.2 or later](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#multi-threading)), the rewritten GIL means that while threading still gains you nothing on CPU bound tasks, it doesn't run substantially slower and eat a core on nothing but GIL overhead.

Comment: Simplified code to not use `Queue` as it's not needed for this example + I they were the mistakes you pointed out.
I added some code to measure the start and end of each request and the output and make the question clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem (when testing against a handful of internet servers, each one repeated a few times, all requests are serviced in about the same time, no steadily increasing delays), but your new output points to a completely different issue: I suspect the "local server" you're using may not be multithreaded (or otherwise able to service multiple requests at once).

Your own output indicates the threads are launching in parallel, but requests are being serviced serially; if it was GIL handoff causing problems, I'd expect to see all of them delayed a bit (one thread would get some work done, then another would do some more, etc.), not each one running to completion before the next starts. This smacks of a problem on the server side, where the server is handling requests to completion before it services additional connections.

Taking a stab at psychic debugging, did you by any chance implement the five second request time by adding a sleep in the server code, possibly after `accept` returns, but before launching a thread to service it? Or just not use threading on the server at all?

Comment: Wow this was it. The local server I had running didn't have multithreading enabled and was blocking in the response. Should I close the question or at least rename it because it's not a Python problem and was infact an issue testing the performance?

Comment: @tt_Gantz: I wouldn't close it, since really, in its current state, it asks a question that someone might legitimately ask in the future, for the same reasons, and it (now) gives enough information to help them identify their own problem.

Answer (score -1):

Python threads are slow! Python has a GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) which uses a mutex to serialize access to internals. You might want to have a look at Jython which doesn't have a GIL and can fully exploit multiprocessor systems.

Comment: The OP is aware of the GIL having mentioned it in the question; the threads should be I/O bound though, and typically threading to coordinate parallel tasks that block on I/O is fine. "The GIL is bad, so never ever use threads" is a vast oversimplification, and adds nothing. And given how terrible Jython support has been (over five years behind the language spec), it wouldn't be my first recommendation.